# Is HLS Streaming Supported on Tizen TV Emulator?

Tags: html5-video, http-live-streaming, m3u8, tizen-emulator, tizen-tv

I need to play an HTTP live stream (m3u8 playlist), and it does not work in the sample AVPlay app. I wonder whether the problem is that the emulator does not support HLS or not. However, I can play the individual streams in the playlist.

I am getting the following response from the URL: (I modified the values randomly to ensure that the streams are not accessible)

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-
ID=1,BANDWIDTH=678000,RESOLUTION=768x432,CODECS="avc1.77.30, mp4a.40.2"
https://livestream-f.akamaihd.net/i/2025iz9od4_1@99633/index_123_avp.m3u8
sd=10&dw=100&rebase=on&hdntl=exp=150977~acl=%2fil~hmac=adfe2a9bdd6
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-
ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1756000,RESOLUTION=864x486,CODECS="avc1.77.30, mp4a.40.2"
https://livestream-
f.akamaihd.net/i/20251386_6385852_lsifljk7m8ab9906ud4_1@99633/index_5432_av-
p.m3u8?
sd=10&dw=100&rebase=on&hdntl=exp=1500980977~acl=%2fi
%2f2025135852_lsifljk7m8aw9iz6dd4_1%4099633%2f*~data=hdntl~hmac=add2addcaee
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-
ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1756000,RESOLUTION=864x486,CODECS="avc1.77.30, mp4a.40.2"
https://livestream-
f.akamaihd.net/i/20251386_6385852_lsifljk7m87w9iz6dd4_1@99633/index_1771_av-
b.m3u8?
sd=10&dw=100&rebase=on&hdntl=exp=1500980977~acl=%2fi
%2f2025m8aw9iz6dd4_1%4099633%2f*~data=hdntl~hmac=23dkjddc9579ulp3bd52ce2a9bd
...
...
...
```

Comment: Did it work with any other stream (http, or local file)? I try to get demo AVPlayer working in emulator, but it fails with "webapis is not defined" error.

Comment: If you get this error, you will need to include the WebAPI library in the “index.html” file:

<head>
...
 <script type="text/javascript" src="$WEBAPIS/webapis/webapis.js"></script>
...
</head>

Comment: I did. My app works well on real TV, but fails in emulator. I can't figure out why.

Comment: Hi Alex, which emulator version are you using, 4.0? I recently updated Tizen Studio and started getting the same error. Did you find any solutions?

Comment: Version 4.0. I haven't found a solution.